# I have two different headers because of Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, header

So the problem is that I'm new to REACT, I used create-react-app and added a Router function to route between components. Now I created a header which everything was okay with, but I added a hamburger-menu so I could route between my pages and suddenly my Header just got itself duplicated on my webpage.

App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import './Header.css'
import SideDrawer from "./SideDrawer";
import Header from './Header'
import Backdrop from './Backdrop'
import Home from "./Home";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
import SignupPage from "./SignupPage";
import RegisterEventPage from "./RegisterEventPage";


class App extends Component {
    state = {
        sideDrawerOpen: false
    };

    drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen};
        });
    };


    backDropClickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({sideDrawerOpen: false});
    };

    render() {
        let sideDrawer;
        let backdrop;

        if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
            sideDrawer = <SideDrawer/>;
            backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backDropClickHandler}/>;
        }

        return (
            <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
                <Header drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
                {sideDrawer}
                {backdrop}

            <Router>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/loginPage" component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path="/SignupPage" component={SignupPage}/>
                <Route path="/RegisterEventPage" component={RegisterEventPage}/>
            </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Header.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DrawerToggleButton from './DrawerToggleButton';
import './Header.css';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <header className="main_toolbar">
                <nav className="toolbar_navigation">
                    <div>
                        <DrawerToggleButton click={this.props.drawerClickHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="toolbar_logo"><a href="/">IceBreaker</a></div>
                    <div className="spacer"></div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

So if I for example remove  from App.js my second header suddenly disappears.

[Image of two headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlCIY.png)

Comment: use ’import Header as MainHeader from...’

Answer (score 0):

Render your header inside the router:
I also recomend you to use a switch in your router

You will need to import it : 
 `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";`

```js
return (
            <div style={{height: '100%'}}>

               <Router>
                  <Header drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
                  {sideDrawer}
                  {backdrop}

                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                  <Route path="/loginPage" component={LoginPage}/>
                  <Route path="/SignupPage" component={SignupPage}/>
                  <Route path="/RegisterEventPage" component={RegisterEventPage}/>
               </Switch>
            </Router>
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: It didn't help.